# Erro when I to try to use import

Tags: python-3.x, import, importerror, relative-import

I am coding an application that has 2 services integrated with rabbitmq(publisher and consumer).
I have a folder lib that contains a class manager_mq, that is used to manage the process of pub/sub of my application.

My structured the directory to be like the image:

[image]

In my consumer or publisher .py file, When I try to import manager_mq an error is returned.

My import to be like that:

```
from services.lib.manager_mq import Manager
```

However, an error is returned on the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "consumer.py", line 5, in <module>      
    from services.lib.manager_mq import Manager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'services'
```

I am tried to use relative import but the error occurs yet.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "consumer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..lib.manager_mq import Manager
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here both absolute and relative imports won't work. For more information, check out [Importing from Parent Directory](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#case-3-importing-from-parent-directory).

In this case it would probably be the easiest to use `sys.path` to add the `lib` to the path.

```
application
├── consumer
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── consumer.py
└── lib
    └── __init__.py
    └── manager_mq.py
```

`manager_mq.py` test code:

```
class Manager:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print('test')
```

`consumer.py` test code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../lib")

from manager_mq import Manager

m = Manager()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Gilbert Tanner! You help me a lot!